# Print the results of a vlookup to a cell in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, indexing, match, vlookup

I have been working on a solution to this problem for a few hours now and I am basically no where except knowing that I don't know how to do it...So here goes.

I want to take the original data that I have in Excel that have 'code#s' for each 'category#'. With those 'code#s', I can look up the 'category#' name.

[image: Here is a picture of my data, lookups, and what I want the final result to look like.]

This has been so challenging because there are a varying number of categories for every 'title#'.

I have tried printing the 'category#' name next to 'title#', but it is seemingly impossible because Excel goes through every row in the original data and gives a True, False or #N/A instead of selecting and printing only the true statements without copying down a thousand rows. I want it to go through all the possibilities and only select the categories based on the criteria that they have the same 'title#' and their lookup code matches somewhere in the lookup table.

Thanks if you can offer any sort of help.

Here are some of the formulas I have tried:

```
IF(AND($M$5=TOP_TREND_CONTRIBUTORS!$W$2:$W$253,MATCH(TOP_TREND_CONTRIBUTORS!$A$2:$A$253,'Category Lookup'!$D$3:$D$30,0)<>"#N/A"),TOP_TREND_CONTRIBUTORS!$A$2:$A$253,FALSE)
```

....where M5, W:W is the 'title#', A:A is the code for the lookup-in that part I am trying to say that they are valid if the code registers in the lookup table and the 'title#s' are equal. The last part I am trying to get it to print the 'code#s' that are valid. But that only works when I drag the formula down all the rows.

Comment: What formulae are you using?  Can you post them here?

Comment: Why there are so many "title2" in final result, but occurs only one time in original data?

Comment: sorry that is an oversight on my part; I'm trying to say that the amount of 'categories' will be different for every single 'title'

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I just tried to get from your original data and lookup table to the final result. I used `VLOOKUP` to put categories next to titles and then used pivot table to present the data in the way you wanted (after changing some settings of pivot table and fields). Is that what you need? (some words are in Polish, it doesn't matter).

[image: data]

Comment: that's not exactly what I was looking for. From the original data, I need to pull the categories with the highest trends in order, so I'm not really sure where they fall next to the title column. I figured it out this morning and I think I'm going to use the large and if functions to identify the highest trends and then use vlookup to get the category name....thank you so much for the help though